# App is crashing on Android 11 on creating backup realm file

Tags: android, database, realm, database-backups, internal-storage

My app crashes on Android 11 when I am going to save the realm database file in internal storage. It's working in all other android versions . I have tried by adding permissions like
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE . But nothing works for me

```
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        EXPORT_REALM_PATH = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);        
        EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME = "myrealm.realm";
        **// I want to create a backup file for my database (realm)**
        // create a backup file
    public void backup() {
    // First check if we have storage permissions
    checkStoragePermissions(SystemUtils.getActivity());
        File file = new File(EXPORT_REALM_PATH,EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME);
        // if backup file already exists, delete it
        file.delete();
        // copy current realm to backup file
        realm.writeCopyTo(file); // crashes here on Android 11

       String msg = "FilexportedtoPath: " + EXPORT_REALM_PATH + "/" + EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME;
        Toast.makeText(SystemUtils.getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
     }

            private void checkStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permission3 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && permission3 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
      
    } 
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        SystemUtils.getActivity(), "Thanks ! Now you can proceed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notGranted = false;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SystemUtils.getActivity(), "You have not given permission to access gallery ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do something like displaying a message that he didn`t allow the app to access the gallery and you wont be able to let him select from gallery
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code , is it enough for you to understand ? @blackapps

Comment: If the app crashes you did not catch an exception. Please post the relevant lines from the Logcat.

Comment: `file.delete();` ? Check if delete() returns true. Only call delete if file exists(). Please adapt code. Did you request permissions at runtime?

Comment: file.delete(); returns true automatically if file already exists and yes i have taken run time permissions

Comment: `file.delete(); returns true automatically if file already exists` Not if the file cannot be deleted. And it also returns false if there is no file.

Comment: Yes, you are right but it's not an issue here and it's not crashing the application . The crash is in the below-line realm.writeCopyTo(file);

Comment: The issue probably is if you got write access. And you can check that with delete() if you implement it in the normal way. And why didnt you post the logs or tell which exception?